# Trying to get value of current_user saved in a hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple rails app in which, in one of the forms, I am trying to save the value of current user into a field using hidden field tag.

My application controller has user_authenticate method which is also setting value of @current_user as below.

---

### ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  protected 

def authenticate_user
  if session[:user_id]
     # set current user object to @current_user object variable
    @current_user = User.find session[:user_id] 
    return true 
  else
    redirect_to(:controller => 'sessions', :action => 'login')
    return false
  end
end
def save_login_state
  if session[:user_id]
    redirect_to(:controller => 'sessions', :action => 'home')
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
end

end
```

### The receipt model is defined with belongs_to user as below.

### Receipt model

```
class Receipt < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :currency
  belongs_to :user
end
```

### and the view for form has a hidden field tag as below.

### Form

```
<%= form_for(receipt) do |f| %>

  <% if receipt.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(receipt.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this receipt from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% receipt.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<div align="center" style="text-align: right; width: 50%">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :receipt_date %>
    <%= f.date_select :receipt_date %>
  </div>
</br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :receipt_amount %>
    <%= f.text_field :receipt_amount %>
  </div>
</br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Currency%>
    <%= f.collection_select :currency_id, Currency.all, :id, :currency %>
  </div>
</br>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :user_id => @current_user %>
  </div>

</br>
 <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Yet when I save the record I get an error - "User must exist". So essentially, the user field is going as 'nil'.

My receipt controller is like this

---

### ReceiptsController

```
class ReceiptsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_receipt, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /receipts
  # GET /receipts.json
  def index
    @receipts = Receipt.all
  end

  # GET /receipts/1
  # GET /receipts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /receipts/new
  def new
    @receipt = Receipt.new
  end

  # GET /receipts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /receipts
  # POST /receipts.json
  def create
    @receipt = Receipt.new(receipt_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @receipt.save
        format.html { redirect_to @receipt, notice: 'Receipt was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @receipt }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @receipt.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /receipts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /receipts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @receipt.update(receipt_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @receipt, notice: 'Receipt was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @receipt }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @receipt.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /receipts/1
  # DELETE /receipts/1.json
  def destroy
    @receipt.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to receipts_url, notice: 'Receipt was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_receipt
      @receipt = Receipt.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def receipt_params
      params.require(:receipt).permit(:receipt_date, :receipt_amount, :currency_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have devise, this should do it for you,  notice the non instance variable, without the @

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  </div>
```

or otherwise, in your situation.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user.id %>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am not using Devise. I tried your solution (second example) and it gives me following error. **undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass** for the like `<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user.id %>`

Comment: It worked when I included `before_action :authenticate_user` in my controller and the used hidden field in my view as `  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user.id %>
  </div>`

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you won't have to render the current_user id in the form, you already have a session to identify the user, simply scope your receipt under the current user in your receipts controller:

```
class ReceiptsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    receipt = current_user.receipts.new(receipt_params)
    if receipt.save
      # redirect
    else
      # render new
    end
  end
end
```

This also guards against non-authenticated users being able to update someone else's receipts. If you are authenticating the user anyways and have access to current user in the controller this is the way to go.

Comment: I tried this and it gives me following error.
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<ReceiptsController:0xab0c3d8>

`Extracted source (around line #28):
26
27
28
29
30
31
              
  # POST /receipts.json
  def create
    @receipt = current_user.receipts.new(receipt_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @receipt.save`

Comment: You need to authenticate the user beforehand of course, so put `before_action :authenticate_user` in the controller,

Comment: It worked when I included `before_action :authenticate_user` in my controller and the used hidden field in my view as `  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @current_user.id %>
  </div>`

Comment: Right the point is you don't need that field, you already have access to @current_user in your controller